# Android Camera Byte[] data, how does it store 32 bit pixels?

Tags: android, image-processing

From what I understand, each pixel is represented by 4 bytes (a,r,g,b).  How is it possible to store this in a byte[] array where the size is the number of pixels in the image.

The following code works as expected (rotates the image)

```
rotatedData = new byte[data.length];
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        rotatedData[x * height + height - y - 1] = data[x + y * width];
}
data = rotatedData;
int tmp = width; // Here we are swapping, that's the difference to #11
width = height;
height = tmp;
```

Comment: Are you sure it's 32b data? An equally valid way to store it that would fit with your description is `one byte = 0xaarrggbb` or similar.

Comment: How can you store a number 0-255 in 2 bits?

Comment: You don't; that's my question. Are you *sure* that what you have is 32b worth of colour data per pixel? Even if the data captured is 32b, the return value of any particular function to access that data doesn't necessarily need to return that much detail. A function to return a `Byte[]` would make sense to use a scheme like I mentioned. I don't know Android at all, but I do know it isn't possible to store 32b in 8b.

Comment: But it's a camera image direct from the android camera, it's hard to imagine it being only 32 possible colors?

Comment: Plus the format in the android docs says argb_8888

Comment: perhaps some code describing how you are accessing the data would be helpful?

Comment: I am not really seeing where you are getting your "data" byte array from, but on the original bitmap does bitmapName.getConfig() return ARGB_8888?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re talking about decoding the “NV21” representation of the camera preview image, that consists of a block containing one byte of luminance data per pixel, followed by another block containing colour data with one sample for each 2×2 pixel block. Colour data has lower resolution than luminance because the human eye is less sensitive to colour detail.

For sample code that decodes this format to regular Android Bitmap-format ARGB pixels, see the `DecodeNV21` routine [here](https://github.com/ldo/3D-Compass/blob/master/src/CameraUseful.java).